# Wordpress no Localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost

Possuo um site Wordpress online, e preciso colocar esse site na minha máquina local. Tenho um ambiente com WampServer. 
Como posso fazer para passar esse site para minha máquina local? 
Apenas copiando os arquivos e fazendo backup do banco consigo desenvolver esta situação?

Comment: veja se isto ajuda https://www.bloglite.net/como-migrar-o-wordpress-de-servidor-guia/, tem ainda este mais preciso: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/

Comment: muito bom tutorial, mas minha duvida é que, esse tutorial ensina a hospedar ele de local para online, para coloca-lo local, de online para local utilizo o mesmo processo?

Comment: o segundo tutorial explica isso, eu penso que o processo para passar de local para web e de web para local seja igual ou muito parecido

Answer (score 0):

Este plugin **[Backup and Move Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backup-and-move/)** faz isso de maneira super fácil.

Comment: obrigado vou averiguar...

Answer (score 0):

Eu me lembro ter pegado um plugin em Wordpress para migrar de um servidor para outro.

Acredito que seja o: Duplicator - Wordpress Migration Plugin. https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: obrigado vou averiguar...

Answer (score 0):

O melhor plugin para fazer isso chama se All in One WP Migration, você vai instalar ele na sua aplicação e vai exportar usando esse plugin como "file" dai instala o plugin na sua aplicação local e clica em importar, dai ele vai todo correto sem erros, o que não acontece com a maioria dos outros plugins com essa finalidade. Qualquer dúvida só perguntar!